# How to learn Windows Server Management

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, remote-access

I am new to Windows Server Management and have a little experience with linux server management before. Right now, I manage a small network composed of 4 servers shipped with Windows server 2008 r2. We run our property software on those servers and want to monitor the server performance in order to make sure servers hardware are good enough to run those applications. And my questions are:

1. Do I need to add an active directory role in one of the servers? 
   PS: Actually, I have skimmed the book windows server 2008 inside out(WSIO), but it seems that it is prepared for large company network and it is such a thick book.
2. How can I set the MMC to enable monitoring all the servers in one console instead of remote  desktop.
3. Any easy and good book for Windows Server Management. The WSIO seems a good reference but not a good tutorial.

Comment: Windows administration is not a light topic; hence the very thick books about it. I'd highly recommend bringing in a  consultant or investing the (significant) time to learn how to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 you can choose to use active directory or not.
active directory extend the security boundry from one server to all servers in active directroy.
but, active directory useful in the large enterprise network.
other hands, you can set the same password for local administrators account of 4 servers.
when user name and password is same in two servers, you can access the logon user in console to other servers as credential of users as the same name.

2 you can use the customized mmc console.

```
start > run > mmc.exe
```

you can show the mmc console. and add the snap-in using .
and, save the mmc console.

actually, you need to install the administration pack. for using that services management snap-in that is not installed on local server.

Please refer the follow link:

Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449475(WS.10).aspx

3 -